# vscode debug error. cannot connect to runtime

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to debug the current .js file opened in vscode.  Press F5 to run. Get error:"cannot connect to runtime. Make sure that runtime is in legacy debug mode."

The debug console shows error:
Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be determined (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858)

node.exe is in my path.  And .vscode/launch.json contains type:node, request:launch, program:${file}.

Why the "cannot connect to runtime" error?

```
 "configurations": [
   {
     "type": "node",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Program",
     "program": "${file}"
   },
   {
     "type": "node",
     "request": "attach",
     "name": "Attach",
     "port": 5858
   }]
```

Comment: What's the version of VS Code?

Comment: You might try adding the "protocol":"legacy",attribute.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_supported-nodelike-runtimes

Comment: node --version is v6.11.2
When I specify protocol=legacy I get 
"Cannot connect to runtime; make sure that runtime is in 'legacy' debug mode."
Setting protocol=inspector, error is:
Ensure Node was launched with --inspect. Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms

Comment: I have to do more testing on this.  Created new project. Am able to debug it.